# Improve performance mapping certain elements within a dataframe based on other values

Tags: python, python-2.7, performance, pandas, dataframe

I have a large csv sheet containing data along the lines of the following:

```
     clients   id    products type1 type2  value_x  value_y
0    bob       111   pen      A     X      100      5
1    zoe       112   glue     A     Y      33       3
2    alex      113   glue     B     Y      50       1
3    alex      114   pen      A     X      100      5
4    bob       115   pen      B     Y      70       1
```

My goal is to map comparable ids from each client within a new dataframe that would look like this:

```
     bob  zoe alex
id                
111  111  NaN  114
112  NaN  112  NaN
113  NaN  NaN  113
114  111  NaN  114
115  115  NaN  NaN
```

I map these ids by comparing the fields products, type1, type2, value_x, value_y. The only issue is that I am currently doing this by iterating through every row, which takes about 30 min due to the size of the real dataframe. Furthermore, while the values for products, type1, and type2 are fixed, value_x and value_y can contain a degree of tolerance which I would set with `df.value_x.between(lower, upper)`(not in my example below for simplicity).
Is there a way to speed up this process, or some other way of mapping these comparable values?

code used:

```
data = {'type1': ['A', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'B'],
       'type2': ['X', 'Y', 'Y', 'X', 'Y'],
       'value_x': [100, 33, 50, 100, 70],
       'value_y': [5, 3, 1, 5, 1],
       'clients': ['bob', 'zoe', 'alex', 'alex', 'bob'],
       'id': ['111', '112', '113', '114', '115'],
       'products': ['pen', 'glue', 'glue', 'pen', 'pen']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df_mapped = pd.DataFrame(index=df.id, columns=df.clients.unique())

for row in df.itertuples():
    row_client = row[1]
    row_id = row[2]
    row_product = row[3]
    row_type1 = row[4]
    row_type2 = row[5]
    row_value_x = row[6]
    row_value_y = row[7]

    for client in df_mapped.columns:
        try:
            comparable_id = df[(df.clients == client) &
                               (df.type1 == row_type1) &
                               (df.type2 == row_type2) &
                               (df.value_x == row_value_x) &
                               (df.value_y == row_value_y) &
                               (df.products == row_product)]['id'].iloc[0]
        except IndexError:
            comparable_id = np.nan

        df_mapped.loc[row_id, client] = comparable_id

print df_mapped
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see no issues with your logic, but see a ~12x speed-up through 2 changes:

- Drop down to `numpy` for array scalar comparisons.
- Use `.iat` accessor to set result dataframe entries.

Benchmarking results below.

```
import pandas as pd, numpy as np

data = {'type1': ['A', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'B'],
       'type2': ['X', 'Y', 'Y', 'X', 'Y'],
       'value_x': [100, 33, 50, 100, 70],
       'value_y': [5, 3, 1, 5, 1],
       'clients': ['bob', 'zoe', 'alex', 'alex', 'bob'],
       'id': ['111', '112', '113', '114', '115'],
       'products': ['pen', 'glue', 'glue', 'pen', 'pen']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

def jp(df):

    df_mapped = pd.DataFrame(index=df.id, columns=df.clients.unique())

    df_values = df.values

    for i in range(df_values.shape[0]):
        row_client, row_id, row_product, row_type1, row_type2, row_value_x, row_value_y = df_values[i]

        for idx, client in enumerate(df_mapped):
            s = df.loc[(df_values[:, 0] == client) &
                       (df_values[:, 3] == row_type1) &
                       (df_values[:, 4] == row_type2) &
                       (df_values[:, 5] == row_value_x) &
                       (df_values[:, 6] == row_value_y) &
                       (df_values[:, 2] == row_product), 'id']

            try:
                comparable_id = s.iat[0]
            except IndexError:
                comparable_id = np.nan

            df_mapped.iat[i, idx] = comparable_id

    return df_mapped

def original(df):
    df_mapped = pd.DataFrame(index=df.id, columns=df.clients.unique())

    for row in df.itertuples():
        row_client = row[1]
        row_id = row[2]
        row_product = row[3]
        row_type1 = row[4]
        row_type2 = row[5]
        row_value_x = row[6]
        row_value_y = row[7]

        for client in df_mapped:
            try:
                comparable_id = df[(df.clients == client) &
                                   (df.type1 == row_type1) &
                                   (df.type2 == row_type2) &
                                   (df.value_x == row_value_x) &
                                   (df.value_y == row_value_y) &
                                   (df.products == row_product)]['id'].iloc[0]
            except IndexError:
                comparable_id = np.nan

            df_mapped.loc[row_id, client] = comparable_id

    return df_mapped

assert original(df).equals(jp(df))

%timeit jp(df)        # 7.5ms
%timeit original(df)  # 99ms
```